# What is the best stage and hero for high lvl items to sell for mana?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I want high lvl stuff for **mana** and I'm getting the £40 version at X-mas so what will the best lvl be. I'm guessing Lab Assault with a BF DrilL. Any difficulty but I will most likely only be a lvl 74 EV and I may have a lvl 80 friend helping. He has each free hero up to 74 then a summoner up to 76. What lvl would be best with and without my friend?

Comment: Will you be soloing? And which difficulty will you be playing at?

Comment: Improved Q to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lab Assault on Insane or Nightmare is indeed one of the best ways to get top-quality gear as well as obtain mana. Though you don't get nearly as many items from Lab Assault as you would, say, farming a survival map, the quality/sell value of lab assault items far exceeds the cumulative value of any survival loot.

In addition, Lab Assault can be completed for rewards relatively quickly, so doing it over and over again in quick succession yields very large amounts of loot.